# How to realtime monitor webservices on Tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, monitoring

we are implementing webservices with Spring & Apache CXF which run on Tomcat 7, the original idea was to write some kind of monitoring solution that checks if the webservices are available and running ok.

But i guess that instead of writing the monitoring software ourselves there should be some tooling that already exists which could help us monitoring the webservices.

Which tooling could help us monitor the webservice availablity? Or what is the best approach to achieve this? Our support staff should be informed if a webservice goes down, and they should be able to act on data that the montoring tools provide.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've added an additional API endpoint that simply returns a 200 error code. Hook this URL up to something like [pingdom.com](http://pingdom.com) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your own solution, a good approach would be to develop an external scheduled class that checks weather your services are alive every X minutes. If not, it will send the email you want. This will work even if your tomcat dies.

You can also check the JMX technology:
*"The JMX technology provides the tools for building distributed, Web-based, modular and dynamic solutions for managing and monitoring devices, applications, and service-driven networks."*